# How can I optimise operations on dataframe by avoiding loops in python?

Tags: python, pandas, lambda, apply

How can I avoid `for index, row in df.iterrows()`?

My data is like this:

```
import pandas as pd

keys = ['Address', 'CoordinateX', 'CoordinateY']
values = [['Addr1', 'Addr2', 'Addr3'], [0, 1, 1], [9, 2, 1]]
addresses = dict(zip(keys, values))
df = pd.DataFrame(addresses, columns=keys)
R = 1
```

The `df` can be shown as:

```
  Address  CoordinateX  CoordinateY
0   Addr1            0            9
1   Addr2            1            2
2   Addr3            1            1
```

My task is to add a new column `Counts` that stores the number of addresses located within the same area - a circle of a certain radius `R`. However, on the final dataframe I want only one representative address for each area. So the output after calculations would be:

```
  Address  CoordinateX  CoordinateY  Counts
0   Addr1            0            9       1
1   Addr2            1            2       2
```

Initially, I had this code:

```
df_X = pd.DataFrame() # to fill with counts
for idx, row in df.iterrows():
  x1, y1 = row['CoordinateX'], row['CoordinateY']
  addr_count = 0
  indices = [] # to collect idx2 for dropping in df_X
  df2 = df.copy()
  for idx2, row2 in df2.iterrows():
    x2, y2 = row2['Longitude'], row2['Lattitude']
    distance = math.sqrt((x2-x1)**2 + (y2-y1)**2)
    if distance <= R:
      addr_count += 1
      indices.append(idx2)
  if addr_count > 0:
    row['Count'] = addr_count
    df_X = df_X.append(row, ignore_index=True)
    df.drop(indices, inplace=True) # to exclude the rows in next iteration
df_X.shape
```

So there are 2 loops - external and internal on similar data.
Because my original dataframe has couple of thousand rows, I want to optimise the calculation using `pd.apply()`. This is my code that replaces the internal loop with `pd.apply`:

```
def count_items(x1, y1, r, df):
  def is_outside(x2, y2): return r < math.sqrt((x2-x1)**2 + (y2-y1)**2)
  df_new = df[df.apply(lambda a: is_outside(a['CoordinateX'], a['CoordinateY']), axis=1)] # new set with distant addresses only
  return df_new, len(df.index) - len(df_new.index)

def get_counted(r, df):
  df_X = pd.DataFrame() # to fill with counts
  for idx, row in df.iterrows():
    x1, y1 = row['CoordinateX'], row['CoordinateX']
    df2 = df.copy()
    df3, addr_count = count_items(x1, y1, r, df2) # df3 contains now only distant addresses
    if addr_count > 0:
      row['Count'] = addr_count
      df_X = df_X.append(row, ignore_index=True)
    df = df3.copy()
  return df_X

df_c = df.copy()
df_addrX = get_counted(R, df_c)
```

And I have no idea how to enhance the part with the external loop the same way. Can anyone provide with a suggestion, please?
BR, Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

What you need is using combinations function, you may find information [here](https://docs.python.org/fr/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations).

As they say, you may apply :

> combinations('ABCD', 2)

in order to obtain :

> AB AC AD BC BD CD

The first argument of your function is an iterator on you lines, the second is 2 (you want combinations of 2 lines).

You may iterate on the indexes of the rows, so you may obtain couples of indexes of rows, for example.

After that, as soon as you have couples of lines, you may map or iterate on the result in order to apply your function which calculates the distance.

You may stock all this in a DataFrame with the following columns :

> FirstRowIndex
>   SecondRowIndex
>   Distance

Then, just make a `groupby()` on two columns : `FirstRowIndex` and `Distance`, in order to find the elements in the same area, delete those you do not need and keep the indexes you need.

Finally, select the rows corresponding to those indexes in the original `DataFrame`, using `df.loc` for example.

Comment: I checked and this still requires the external loop to provide with the data ...

Comment: Indeed, it seems a confusion matrix may help, let me think about it.

Comment: I updated the answer, I found something that might be a solution for your problem.

Comment: Thanks, I will explore and let you know.

Comment: You may iterate on the indexes of the rows, for example, as you need toi input an iterator to combinations function. I hope this might be helpful.